# What the problems can appear by using log without console.log?

Tags: javascript, this, console.log

What the problems can appear by using log without console.log? Is there any dependence at context, that can be lost?
For example, if i'm using something like this:

```
setTimeout(console.log, 1000, 'hello');
```

or:

```
someFetch().then(console.log, console.log)
```

Comment: It won't work. `console.log.bind(console)` should, however.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol are you sure? The first example works for me.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Works in modern browsers and node.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Huh, so it does. I could've sworn it didn't. When did that change? :D

Comment: ¯|_(ツ)_/¯ who knows?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Not sure :) I was surprised as well  :)

Comment: OP - I'm not sure I understand your question. In your examples you're not using `log` without `console.log`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Added  24 Aug 2012 to [node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/025f53c306d91968b292051404aebb8bf2adb458)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Whenever you have the pattern `f(p.g)` then the method `g` loses its receiving object (`p`).

Comment: @ftor Unless they did `p.g = p.g.bind(p)` :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I get what you're saying, but `log` is a pure function. It doesn't need its context.

Comment: @evolutionxbox is anywhere in docs mentioning that log is pure function?

Comment: @evolutionxbox How come IO related function is pure? :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I guess you meant `log` doesn't use `this` and thus is a function, not a method.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I meant that with the same input given, same output is received. Although I am unsure if there are any side-effects.

Comment: IO is the mother of all side effects.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'd say `console.log` is the second most impure function I could imagine (after the one that reads user input) :) The only reason it exists is side-effect (printing to stdout). Just imagine a function that takes any argument and returns nothing. There is no way it can be pure and non trivial.

Comment: *"is anywhere in docs mentioning that log is pure function?"* `console` and `console.log` are not standardized. You'd have to look at the each environments documentation or implementation of that function.